# Which front-end agreement types go well with a MIT license?

Tags: mit, terminology, license-notice

I've decided on using a MIT license for a software project. Now I would like to go ahead and add agreements to the front-end of a website that uses the MIT licensed software. I looked at the template agreements on Termsfeed but they are not the same as for example those on Ebay. What are the typical agreement types that a small sized open source software project would present the user with on the front-end of a website and can the different agreements listed below be merged into one grand terms of service?

Front-end agreement types offered by [Termsfeed](https://termsfeed.com/):

- Privacy policy
- Terms  of service
- Terms of use
- Terms and conditions
- Return and refund policy

Front-end agreement types used on [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/):

- User agreement
- Privacy
- Cookies
- AdChoice

Comment: This really feels like a... kind of off question. Open source doesn't really do that much for end users of a product: it more affects developers that use the code. The privacy policy of a site feels off-topic, but I'll see what other people think.

Comment: Thank you @Zizouz212, the three questions I've asked so far on Open Source SE are all directly related to development of the same open source software project, so I'll appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about laws other than copyright and those relevant to open source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the licensing of the backend software of a website is irrelevant to decisions about terms of use, privacy policies etc.

Comment: Thank you for your patience everyone. I'm still trying to make a clear distinction between open source and open access since this is my first project dealing with both these. I found the answer to this question useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license you choose for the software that runs the website is orthogonal to the terms you offer to the users of your website. The license - the thing that makes it open source - deals with copyright.

All other terms have nothing to do with that, and there is no interaction between the license and other terms of use. The fact that your website runs open-source software doesn't influence any of the agreements you mentioned, and you can choose them as you would for any website that isn't under an open source license.